# How to optimize code to write data that has more than 1,4 millions rows

Tags: c#, text-files

i've got a text file that has 1,4 millions rows with delimiters

My goal is to write new file based on ID, so if in the data has 10 differents ID , it will create 10 new files and list the data based on the ID

I already finish my code , but my problem is, because the data has 1,4 million rows , it took so long to finish it and my PC can crash .

this is my code that i write

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string tgl = date.Date.ToString("dd");
            string bln = date.Month.ToString("d2");
            string thn = date.Year.ToString();
            string tglskrg = thn + bln + tgl;
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\VA");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\VA\\VA_" + tglskrg);



            string filename = "X:\\exampledata.txt";

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

            //group by first value (ID)
            var groups = lines.Skip(1)
                  .Select(x => x.Split(';'))
                  .GroupBy(x => x[0]).ToArray();

            // iterate groups write the joined lines back to a new file with the key name
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\VA\\VA_" + tglskrg+"\\exampledata_" + group.Key +"_"+tglskrg + ".txt", new[] { "COMPANY CODE;CUSTOMER NUMBER;CUSTOMER NAME;INSERT DATE;TRANSACTION ID;TRANSACTION AMOUNT;ADMIN FEE;TRANSACTION REF;FLAG STATUS;TRANSACTION STATUS" }.Concat(group.Select(x => string.Join(";", x))));
            }

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                string path = @"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\VA\\VA_" + tglskrg + "\\exampledata_" + group.Key + "_" + tglskrg + ".txt";
                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary = true;
                    zip.Password = group.Key + "VA#";
                    zip.AddFile(path, "VA_" + group.Key +"_"+tglskrg);
                    zip.Save(@"C:\Users\Desktop\exampledata_" + group.Key +"_"+tglskrg + ".zip_");
                }
            }
```

Someone say to use StreamReader, but i really don't know how it works and i dont think it will be faster than what i use now

Maybe someone can help me optimize my code?

Comment: There is no point using `StreamReader` or any lazy technique as you are using a `GroupBy`. in fact its taking a long time because you are doing a large job. You need to profile your own code, work out whats taking the most time, and the assessing whether it can be sped up

Comment: @TheGeneral hmm , is there an effective way to group by ID besides the .groupby()? or there is no way else to fix my code

Comment: Is the GroupBy Taking all the time, or the file thrashing or compression? We dont know, you dont know, you need to figure this out

Comment: @TheGeneral hmm, i'll try to debug it 1 by 1 , i dont think the compression make it long , because it stuck when File.WriteAllLines

Comment: @TheGeneral the group by taking all the time, when i run the code to groupby ID, it takes long time to finish it,i think it is because the data will be insert to a variable which make takes time to finish it

Comment: Possibly you could read this file line by line, and append it to the the file with the right ID, and the right zip file. Im not even sure there is a satisfying multi-threaded way to do this that would help that much

Comment: You could also just parse the start of the string until the first `;` it will be better than `string.Split` then you wouldn't need to `Join` as well

Comment: How many different groups / ids do you expect?

Comment: What is the file size? `1.4 millions of rows` Is not very informative (and frankly, doesn’t sound too much unless each row has thousands of symbols).

Comment: @dyukha 183 MB ._.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reading the whole file into memory and then grouping, you should read each line separately and decide into which file it should go.

I omitted some of your file naming logic, to keep the example simple, but this it what it boils down to:

```
var writers = new Dictionary<string, TextWriter>();
const string header = "COMPANY CODE;CUSTOMER NUMBER;CUSTOMER NAME;INSERT DATE;TRANSACTION ID;TRANSACTION AMOUNT;ADMIN FEE;TRANSACTION REF;FLAG STATUS;TRANSACTION STATUS";
const string inputFile = "X:\\exampledata.txt";
const string outputPath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\VA\\";

using (var reader = File.OpenText(inputFile))
{
    // skip header
    reader.ReadLine();

    try
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            // read one line and separate key and value
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var separatorIndex = line.IndexOf(';');
            var id = line.Substring(0, separatorIndex);
            var value = line.Substring(separatorIndex + 1);

            // get a writer or create one
            if (!writers.TryGetValue(id, out var writer))
            {
                writer = File.CreateText($"{outputPath}{id}.txt");
                writer.WriteLine(header);
                writers.Add(id, writer);
            }

            // write the line to the correct file
            writer.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // dispose all the writers
        foreach (var writer in writers.Values)
        {
            writer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm the out var writer has error message in the if condition , the name var doesnt exist in the current context and the trygetvalue has some valid arguements

Comment: @EnricoHasnawi What error? Are you using an older C# version? In that case do `TextWriter writer; if (!writers.TryGetValue(id, out writer))` which is the same in pre-C#7.

Comment: @ckuri hmm i use the 2010 visual studio express c#

Comment: If possible, upgrade to VS 2019 Community. if not, use the 2 lines from @ckuri to replace the if-statement

Comment: @EnricoHasnawi C#7 is part of Visual Studio 2017. So I would recommend to update as C#7 and C#8 (Visual Studio 2019) have many great features and the Community versions are free.

Comment: @wertzui it works well and so fast, btw how can i put the id too? because ur code make the id dissapear in the data

Comment: Change `writer.WriteLine(value);` to `writer.WriteLine(line);`